# How to detect non-number character in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a function that contains the following loop:

```
    While v_start >= v_stop do
    set v_msg := concat(v_msg,v_start,v_delimiter);
    set v_start := v_start + v_step;
    end while;
```

When I call the function, I pass the following parameter:

```
    select a06_counter_loop(10,-5, -3, '-->') as 'The Loop Output';
```

It should return:

```
    10-->7-->4-->1-->-2-->-5
```

But it returned:

```
    10-->7-->4-->1-->-2-->-5-->
```

My question is that how do I get rid of the last non-number character?

Let me know if you need the entire code for the function.

Thanks,
Perri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    set v_msg := v_start;
    set v_start := v_start + v_step;
    While v_start >= v_stop do
       set v_msg := concat(v_msg,v_delimiter, v_start);
       set v_start := v_start + v_step;
    end while;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this by using [**CONCAT_WS(separator,str1,str2,...)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

```
While v_start >= v_stop do
set v_msg := CONCAT_WS(v_delimiter,v_msg,v_start);
set v_start := v_start + v_step;
end while;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/31922)

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot change the order of the parameters getting passed.